# Funcion $_FILES error: Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp\subir.php on line 14

Tags: php, html, ftp, server

Mi problema es el siguiente intento subir un documento por php usando filezilla es un pequeño programa de prueba pero al parecer no estoy implementando correctamente el comando `$_FILES` mi codigo es el siguiente

```
<?php
    $ftp_server="127.0.0.1";
    $ftp_usuario="admin";
    $ftp_pass="123456";
    $con_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("no se pudo conectar a $ftp_server");
    
    if( ftp_login($con_id,$ftp_usuario,$ftp_pass)){
        echo 'conectado correctamente';
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['archivo']['name']);
        $source_file=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $destino="archivos";
        $nombre=$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
        //ftp_pass($con_id,true);
        if(ftp_put($con_id, $destino.'/'.$nombre, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)){
            echo 'Archivo subido correctamente';
        }
        else{
            echo 'no se pudo subir el archivo';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'no se pudo conectar';
        exit;
    }
?>
```

el html correspondiente es el siguiente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="./subir.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="archivo">
            <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

el error que me da es: conectado correctamente

Notice: Undefined index: archivo in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp\subir.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: archivo in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp\subir.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: archivo in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp\subir.php on line 12

Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp\subir.php on line 14
no se pudo subir el archivo

gracias de antemano
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los archivos son subidos en un array donde, partiendo del índice `0` encontrarás cada archivo que haya sido agregado a través del `input` del formulario. Si se trata de un solo archivo, intenta así: `$_FILES[0]['archivo']['name']` si es un número indeterminado de archivos puedes iterar para obtener la información de cada uno.

Comment: lo intente pero ahora me da el error Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_FILES);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: me da array(0) { } parece que no esta recibiendo el dato digo el archivo

Comment: Puede que debas poner el `action` así: `action="../subir.php"`, suponiendo que `subir.php` se encuentra en la carpeta precedente. Debes poner ahí una ruta exacta para el archivo que recibirá el POST. ¿Estás seguro de que estás adjuntado (seleccionando) un archivo?

Comment: aparentemente si obtiene el archivo adjunte imagen en arriba de como se ve pero por alguna razon funciona

Comment: Puede que haya problemas por el tipo de archivo, el tamaño, etc. Quizá deberías revisar el log de errores buscando información más precisa de por qué no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno pues aparentemente si invierto el if y realizo 2 consultas funciona no entiendo muy bien la diferencia pero funciona:

```
<?php

$ftp_server="127.0.0.1";
$ftp_usuario="admin";
$ftp_pass="123456";

$con_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("no se pudo conectar a $ftp_server");
$lr = ftp_login($con_id, $ftp_usuario, $ftp_pass);    
if( (!$con_id) || (!$lr) ){
    echo 'no se pudo conectar';
    exit;
}
else{
    echo 'conectado correctamente';
    $temp=explode(".", $_FILES['archivo']['name']);
    //var_dump($_FILES);
    $source_file=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino="archivos";
    $nombre=$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
//  ftp_pass($con_id,true);
    $subio=ftp_put($con_id, $destino.'/'.$nombre, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
    if($subio){
        echo 'Archivo subido correctamente';
    }
    else{
        echo 'no se pudo subir el archivo';
    }
}
?>
```

si alguien me aclara la diferencia lo agradesco

Fuente: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp1F5VQaWaw